# Can we check for prerequisites in SharePoint hosted app before installing, if yes then how?

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to restrict SharePoint hosted app from install if it does not fulfill the prerequisites requires for the app.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more clear about the pre requisites? If all technical prerequisites are not met then SharePoint itself will not allow to install the app.

Comment: Mean that list/library, group required in app